# codeigniter loading the wrong image size

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, image-resizing

I made a function in CodeIgniter so when I add a picture of a product it uploads the regular size (product_foto) and the thumbnail size (product_foto_thumb). On the 'all products' page the pictures are all the thumbnail size which I like but when I click on a product to go to the detail page the image is still as small and its still the same size as the thumbnail picture while I'm loading the regular picture on that view page.

This is my upload function in my controller file:

```
public function upload(){

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
            $config['max_size']    = '0';
            $config['max_width']  = '0';
            $config['max_height']  = '0';
            $config['encrypt_name']= true;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);


    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
    }else{
       //Main image
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
        $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width'] = 640;
        $config['height'] = 380;

        //Thumb image
        $dataThumb = $this->upload->data();
        $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
        $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
        $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['width'] = 168;
        $configThumb['height'] = 150;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);

        $this->image_lib->resize();


        $this-> db-> insert('products', array(
            'product_foto' => $data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'],
            'product_foto_thumb' => $dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'],

            'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
            'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
            'product_categorie' => $this-> input->post('product_categorie'),
            'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
            'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
        ));
        $data['img'] = base_url().
        '/upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
        $dataThumb['img'] = base_url().
        '/upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];

        header('location:https://www.example.com/Product/');
}
```

My view file where I'm loading the big size picture:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="<?php echo base_ur().'upload/'$product['product_foto'] ?>">

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

My thumbnail view file:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
<div class="col-lg-2">
<div id="product">
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Products/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
<?php echo '<img src="upload/'.$product['product_naam']; ?> </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Show us the thumb view code as well.

Comment: Ok I edited it man. You can see the thumbnail view now in my question

Comment: Can you check it? I edited my question

Comment: Well you have pasted very bug full code for your thumb. Why you are using product_naam? It should be product_foto_thumb.

Comment: Yeh I changed it to product foto thumb now

Answer (score 0):

See the code bellow. I think it will solve your problem for sure.

```
public function upload() {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']    = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';
        $config['encrypt_name']= true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);


        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
        }else{
           //Main image
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = 640;
            $config['height'] = 380;

            //Thumb image
            $dataThumb = $this->upload->data();
            $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/'.'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['width'] = 168;
            $configThumb['height'] = 150;

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this-> db-> insert('products', array(
                'product_foto' => 'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'],
                'product_foto_thumb' => 'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'],

                'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
                'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
                'product_categorie' => $this-> input->post('product_categorie'),
                'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
                'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
            ));
            $data['img'] = base_url().
            '/upload/new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $dataThumb['img'] = base_url().
            '/upload/thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];

            header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/Product/');
        }
    }
}
```

Your thumb code example

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div id="product">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Your main image example

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div id="product">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto']; ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hello i added the stuff you changed and its still the same :(

Comment: Please clear your upload directory. Then upload a photo. Then see how many files are there and what are their names.

Comment: Please check now. I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Still not working. Do I need to change something in the echo? I echo this on the product detail page: <img src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/'.$product['product_foto' ?>">          Thats how im echoing the big picture but it still shows the small picture on the product detail page

Comment: Hello, I changed like u did and I echo product_foto on the view where I want the big picture and it still shows the thumbnail picture even though I echo the big picture and not the thumb picture..

Comment: can u help me??

Comment: Show us a row of your product table.

Comment: You mean the row where the picture is stored in? its: product_foto

Comment: Yes. Database table row of products

Comment: which row? do i need to mention all rows in products table??

Comment: product_id product_naam product_beshcrijving user_id product_categorie ophaal_plaats product_foto product_foto_thumb date_created date_updated

Comment: those are all the rows in my products column

Comment: Basically all you need to know are these tables: product_foto and product_foto_thumb

Comment: By table row i mean after insert, a live data row of the table.

Comment: How can I find that?

Comment: maybe I need to put the 2 different images in 2 different folders? can you show me code how I can do that?